# Doctrine sql query, where clause not taken into account

Tags: php, orm, doctrine

I suppose my problem is simple but i can't get it fixed...

Here is my query:

```
$this->invites = Doctrine_Query::create()
      ->from('Utilisateur u')
      ->LeftJoin('u.Invites i ON i.utilisateur_id = u.id')
      ->where('u.Invites.invitation_id=', $this->invitation->getId())
      ->execute();
```

and here is my schema:

```
Invites:
  columns:
    invitation_id: {type: integer, notnull: true }
    utilisateur_id: {type: integer, notnull: true }
  relations:
     Utilisateur: {onDelete: CASCADE, local: utilisateur_id, foreign: id}
     Invitation: {onDelete: CASCADE, local: invitation_id, foreign: id, class: Invitation, refClass: Invites}

Utilisateur:
actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
columns:
    email: {type: string(255), notnull: true }
    password: {type: string(255), notnull: true }
    facebook: {type: integer(11), notnull: true }
    smartphone: {type: string(128), notnull: true }
    prenom: {type: string(255), notnull: true }
    nom: {type: string(255), notnull: true }
    daten: {type: timestamp, notnull: true }
    sexe: {type: boolean, notnull: true, default: 0}
    date: {type: timestamp, notnull: true }
```

It seems that my "where" clause in not taking into account. If the invitation_id is 3 i still have an "invite" showing up with invitation_id = 1

Can you help me ?

Thank you

EDIT 
SOlved ! i just needed to add a ? after the equal sign in my where clause :

```
      ->where('u.Invites.invitation_id=?', $this->invitation->getId())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->invites = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->from('Utilisateur u')
    ->LeftJoin('u.Invites i ON i.utilisateur_id = u.id')
    ->where('u.Invites.invitation_id = ?', $this->invitation->getId())
    ->execute();
```